# Dynamic Copy and Special Paste

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I download a report which will always comes columns A:AH, I also always need to re-format it by Special Paste > Multiply by 1 to use formulas. It can vary between 500 and 25000 rows.

I can manually enter "1" into cell D1.

From another post, I have the following code which copies and pastes.

When I paste the data into Sheet2, I want it to be Special Paste Multiplied by 1.

```
Sub DynaCopyPaste()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim s1, s2 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iLastCellS2 As Excel.Range
Dim iLastRowS1 As Long

Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

'get last row
iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp).Row

'get last available cell to paste
Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'copy and paste into Sheet2
s1.Range("A1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "AH")).Copy
iLastCellS2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[image]

I have added a screenshot of my problem. I cannot apply excel functions to the data - please see the function in G11.

What currently works:

1. Type "1" into an empty cell
2. Copy that cell to the clipboard
3. Select all data
4. Paste > Special Paste > Multiply by

My goal is to build an analytics package to manipulate the data, my first step in the code is formatting it so that I can write functions onto the page.

Comment: What do you mean "multiplied by 1"?  Even assuming you're pasting numbers, what does multiplying them by 1 do?

Comment: Per the law of identity, *n * 1 = n*.  What's the intent behind "multiply by 1" that **isn't** already achieved by pasting values only?

Comment: Consider providing some example input data, as well as expected output as part of a [mcve] that will help others assist you.

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim s1, s2 As Excel.Worksheet` only `s2` is of type `Excel.Worksheet` but `s1` is of type `Variant`. You need to declare a type for **every** variable: `Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet, s2 As Excel.Worksheet`

Comment: Sounds like you have _text-that-looks-like-numbers_. You can't paste values and also paste multiplying by 1 in one step. It has to be two steps, because the clipboard will contain the values in question in one of the steps, and the value 1 in the other. That said, the macro recorder should give you most of what you need.

Comment: @PEH thank you I will correct this.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, the macro does work. Understood it has to be two steps... So write a second sub for paste special?

Comment: Not necessarily a second sub, just have the paste special multiply be an additional step, which you can do either before or after you copy the values from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this without actually copying or pasting anything.

```
Dim rngToCopy as Range
'copy and paste into Sheet2
Set rngToCopy = s1.Range("A1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "AH"))
iLastCellS2.Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count, rngToCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
```

If that doesn't work, then I think this should:

```
Dim multiplier as Range
Set multiplier = s1.Range("D1")  '## This is the cell containing your value of 1

Dim rngToCopy as Range, destRange as Range
'## put the values in s2 worksheet:
Set rngToCopy = s1.Range("A1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "AH"))
Set destRange = iLastCellS2.Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count, rngToCopy.Columns.Count)
destRange.Value = rngToCopy.Value

multiplier.Copy
destRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _ 
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. It populated some 0's on blank cells at the top and I tried setting SkipBlanks to True. Small issue, I can delete manually in 5 sec.